# Is checking for exit status other than 0 after a `command || return` unreachable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I found the following patch of code:

```
function some_fun() {    
#[...]
    [ -d ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp ] || mkdir ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp || return 1

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then   # never true?
            mount -t tmpfs none ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp || return 1
    fi
}
```

As far as I understand it, it checks if there is a `tmp` directory in the build directory and, if that is not the case, tries to create it. If that also fails it exits the functions with status code 1.

If that is the case, wouldn't checking for an unsuccessful exit code in the if statement below be pointless? There can't be an unsuccessful command before, because it would've led to the function returning and the if statement never being processed.

Am I correct in thinking that, or is the syntax playing tricks on me?

I'm using bash, btw.

Comment: Good catch. In other matters, you should always quote all references to shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you're sure you know what you're doing. By contrast, while braces can be important, they're not as important as quotes, so `"$MKAPP_BUILDDIR"` is better than `${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}`.

Comment: @G-Man So `[ -d "$MKAPP_BUILDDIR/tmp" ]` would be better style in your opinion? Or just combine the two to make `[ -d "${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp" ]` ?

Comment: You're getting into the realm of personal preference. I would use the first of those options, because the braces in the second aren't functionally necessary, but if you used both quotes and braces, I wouldn't say anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct. The `return` procedure will exit from the function to the originating caller in the script with an exit status of 1.

Therefore the `mount` command will never get processed.

To resolve this, just strip the `if .. then` statement from the mount command:

```
[ -d ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp ] || mkdir ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp || return 1

mount -t tmpfs none ${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp || return 1
```

Therefore if the directory cannot be created: exit with status of 1.
If the creation is successful, then run the `mount` command.

Comment: I recently got the code from someone else. The return statement is behind basically every statement, so that the whole function stops, if one of the statements fails ( I would presume ). Looks like he added it there by mistake.
I will add this to a list of questions I will ask that person.
Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: @Minix you could have tried some configs out by adding `echo` statements yourself. I tried that and came (too late to answer) to the same conclusion as geedoubleya. Don't forget to accept his answer, and upvote (once you have that privilege (which you should get when you accept).

Comment: @Anthon I did, but I wanted to check if there may be some meaning or some special case, that escapes me. Since I still don't have a full overview of all the nooks and crannies of shell script, I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. Thanks for taking the time to look for an answer.

Comment: I agree with the first half of your answer (the `mount` command is currently unreachable) but not the second half (what to do about it). You don’t want to mount onto `${MKAPP_BUILDDIR}/tmp` unless it exists, so (IMNSHO) the correct fix to the script is to leave the `|| return 1` alone, and delete the `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` and the `fi`.

Comment: Good spot @G-Man - thanks! Changed it accordingly.